# Filter out sub-array items that contain a specific key/value pair

Tags: json, jq

I want to use jq to filter out sub-array items that contain a specific key/value pair without filtering out the non-array data.

Input:

```
{
  "log": {
    "foo": {
      ...
    },
    "entries": [
      {
        "request": {
          "method": "OPTIONS",
          "url": "http://www.foobar.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "http://www.foobar.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "log": {
    "foo": {
      ...
    },
    "entries": [
      {
        "request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "http://www.foobar.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried this:

```
jq '(.log.entries[] | select(.request.method != "OPTIONS"))'
```

But then I lose the all of the JSON data above entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly use the `del()` operation on the object that matches your condition

```
del(.log.entries[] | select(.request.method == "OPTIONS"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `|=` assignment operator for modifying sub-elements in-place, e.g:

```
.log.entries |= map(select(.request.method != "OPTIONS"))
```